# how to always use www as the subdomain when using link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a single secure payment page at secure.website.com. Using devise to sign out on that specific page, signing out breaks saying there's no user with id=sign_out. I am guessing this is because when i'm on the secure page, all the links on that page also have secure.website.com/users/sign_out (for example).

rather than always specifying that I want to use www as the url in my link_to...i want to set it to default to that. I tried doing default_url_options but that didn't seem to work. How do I make sure all links are always www subdomain unless otherwise specified?

lastly, what i've been doing to guarantee a page is www unless on the secure page is this:

```
  def always_use_www
    if params[:controller] != 'subscriptions' && request.subdomain != 'www'
      redirect_to :subdomain => "www"
    end
  end
```

i put this in the application controller as a before filter. this seems like a really poor way of doing it. is there a 'right' way? I only want that one secure page to have a different subdomain...otherwise always use www.

Comment: Sounds more like a web server issue, are you running it on apache or nginx? They should have rerouting rules for occasions like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a method `default_url_options`:

```
def default_url_options
  {
    :host => "www.example.com",
    :only_path => false
  }
end
```

You can put this method in application controller of the subcontrollers. To the best of my knowledge, you can only set the whole host, not subdomain. In general, you can put any option `url_for` supports in this method.

Comment: that didn't work when I was on the secure.website.com page...it still rendered all the links as secure.website.com/blabla

Comment: Try also adding :only_path => false.